# ReSharper - how to reanalyze the solution?

Tags: resharper, code-analysis

I've just checked out a solution from Subversion and ReSharper is telling me it has 191 files with errors. In fact, it builds perfectly.

Most of its issues appear to be 'Unknown symbol' ones, where it doesn't recognise namespaces or class names. Looking through the errors, at least it seems to be consistent about which ones it doesn't recognise.

Since ReSharper is completely wrong about this, is there a way I can tell it to start the analysis all over again, in the hope it will get it right this time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the main menu bar, go to ReSharper>Windows>Solution Errors Window. This will bring up the window that shows all errors ReSharper has found. In this window's toolbar there should be a Reanalyze Files with Errors button. Clicking that should refresh ReSharper.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Watching those errors counting themselves down was a very satisfying experience.

Comment: If this doesn't work, close the solution, delete the _ReSharper.[SolutionName] folder in the solution folder, reopen the solution and analyse again. It worked for me.